# How to initialize user inputted String values of an array of objects?

Tags: java

I have this class of PetRecord:

```
 public class PetRecord 
{
    private String name;
    private int age;
    private int weight;
    public PetRecord(String initialName)
    {
        name = initialName;
        age = 0;
    }

    public void set(String newName)
    {
        name = newName; //age and weight are unchanged.
    }

    public PetRecord(int initialAge)
    {
        name = "No name yet.";
        weight = 0;
        if (initialAge < 0)
        {
            System.out.println("Error: Negative age.");
            System.exit(0);
        }
        else
            age = initialAge;
    }

    public void set(int newAge)
    {
        if (newAge < 0)
        {
            System.out.println("Error: Negative age.");
            System.exit(0);
        }
        else
            age = newAge;
        //name and weight are unchanged.
    }

    public PetRecord(double initialWeight)
    {
        name = "No name yet";
        age = 0;
        if (initialWeight < 0)
        {
            System.out.println("Error: Negative weight.");
            System.exit(0);
        }
        else
            weight = initialWeight;
    }

    public void set(double newWeight)
    {
        if (newWeight < 0)
        {
            System.out.println("Error: Negative weight.");
            System.exit(0);
        }
        else
            weight = newWeight; //name and age are unchanged.
    }

    public PetRecord()
    {
        name = "No name yet.";
        age = 0;
        weight = 0;
    }

    public String getName()
    {
        return name;
    }

    public int getAge()
    {
        return age;
    }

    public double getWeight()
    {
        return weight;
    }
}
```

And I have another class that uses PetRecord to have the user input how many Pets there are, input the names of the Pets, and then sort the array alphabetically. I have the sorting part figured out (I think), however I'm having trouble with my loop for setting the names of each PetRecord object. How can I fix this?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class PetSort {


    public static void selectionSort(PetRecord[] a) {
        for (int i = 0; i < a.length - 1; i++) {
            // can add print statement here to help debug sorting algorithm:
            System.out.print("In selectionSort: ");
            for (int k = 0; k < a.length; k++)
                System.out.print(a[k] + ", ");
            System.out.println();

            int indexOfMin = i;
            for (int j = i + 1; j < a.length; j++) {
                if (a[j].getName().compareTo(a[indexOfMin].getName()) > 0)
                    indexOfMin = j;
            }
            PetRecord temp = a[i];
            a[i] = a[indexOfMin];
            a[indexOfMin] = temp;
        }
    }


    public static void main(String args[]){
        int i;
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("How many pets are there?");
        i = s.nextInt();
        PetRecord[] array = new PetRecord[i];
        System.out.println("Please give the names of the pets: ");
        for (int k = 0; k < array.length; k++){
            // This is the line that I'm trying to step through the array, and set the name of each PetRecord Object to what the user inputs.
            //PetRecord array[i] = new PetRecord(s.nextLine());
        }
        selectionSort(array);


    }
}
```

Comment: What is the problem you are facing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I'm having trouble with my loop for setting the names of each
>   PetRecord object. How can I fix this?

you'll need to insert the `println` message inside the loop, otherwise the user might not know how many times to keep entering the required data.

Also, you don't need this entire line within the loop:

```
PetRecord array[i] = new PetRecord(s.nextLine());
```

just this will do:

```
array[i] = new PetRecord(s.nextLine());
```

**note** - the indexer for the `array` is `k` not `i`. If you use `i` to index through the predefined array you'll have an `IndexOutOfBoundsException` exception.

Example:

```
System.out.println("How many pets are there?");
i = s.nextInt();
PetRecord[] array = new PetRecord[i];

for (int k = 0; k < array.length; k++){
    System.out.println("Please give the names of the pets: ");
    array[k] = new PetRecord(s.nextLine());
}
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for the quick response. This fixed most of the problem, but it cuts the input of the names short by 1 when I try and run it. For example, if I input 3 for the number of pets, it only lets me input two names. I tried putting array.length + 1 in the loop, but it goes out of bounds. Also, how can I cast the selectionSort(array); so that it outputs the names of the PetRecords, not the Hash codes?

Comment: @K.Hall okay, let's take it step by step, I don't see a problem with the loop, to be honest. as for printing the names of the pets, you'll need to override the toString() method of the object class within your PetRecord class.

Comment: after you've overridden the toString() then you can simply loop over the PetRecord array and System.out.println(array[i]); where " i " is the for loop control variable. However, if you don't want to use a toString() method you can simply loop over the pet array and invoke the getName() methods to print their names, though I would recommend toString() as you can display the string representation of that object all at once.

Answer (score 1):

first to solve your problem you should test the logic of your program and clean your code to be more organized:

```
  int n; // number of pets
  String petName; // name of pet
  Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
  System.out.println("How many pets are there?");
  n = s.nextInt();
  PetRecord[] arrayPets = new PetRecord[n]; // create array of PetRecord
  for (int i = 0; i < arrayPets.length; i++){
        System.out.println("Please give the name of the pet: ");
        petName = s.nextLine(); // read each pet name
        arrayPets[i] = new PetRecord(petName); //create petRecord object
  }
```

also you have another thing to clean it the constructors of PetRecord should be:

```
// default constructor       
public PetRecord()
{
      name = "";
      age = 0;
      weight = 0;
}
```

in your class you defined instance variables:

```
private int age;
private int weight;
```

so you should put the type of parameters of parameterized constructor same as your instance variables:

```
 // parameterized constructor
 public PetRecord(String initialName,int initialAge,int initialWeight)
 {
        name = initialName;
        if (initialAge < 0)
        {
            System.out.println("Error: Negative age.");
            System.exit(0);
        }
        else
            age = initialAge;

         if (initialWeight < 0)
         {
            System.out.println("Error: Negative weight.");
            System.exit(0);
         }
        else
            weight = initialWeight;
 }
```

you can also if you want overload your constructor like this:

```
// overload constructor with 1 parameter
public PetRecord(String initialName)
{
    name = initialName;
    age = 0;
    weight = 0;
}
// overload constructor with 2 parameters
public PetRecord(int initialAge,int initialWeight)
{
   name = "";
   if (initialAge < 0)
   {
       System.out.println("Error: Negative age.");
       System.exit(0);
   }
   else
       age = initialAge;
   if (initialWeight < 0)
   {
          System.out.println("Error: Negative weight.");
          System.exit(0);
   }
   else
       weight = initialWeight;
}
```

finally you only need to correct your `set` and `get` methods to be the same data type of your instance variables.

Comment: @K. Hall review this notes it's important to fix your constructors